# Brief question in regard to existence and unique (ODE)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am just having a bit of trouble understanding the answer to this problem.

It asks where in the ty plane would the ODE satisfy the existence and uniqueness theorem, that is;

$\mathbf{Thereom}:$ Let the functions $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ by continuous in some rectangle $\alpha \lt t \lt \beta$ and $\gamma \lt y \lt$ $\delta$ containing the point $(t_o,y_o)$. Then in some interval $t_o-h \lt t \lt t_o+h$ contained in $\alpha \lt  t \lt \beta$ there is a unique solution $y=s(t)$ of the initial value problem $y=f(t,y) , y(t_o)=y_o$

One of the examples is , $$y'=(t^2+y^2)^{3/2}$$

So, from what I thought I understood, we must check for continuity of $f(t,y)$ and also for continuity of $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{3}{2}(t^2+y^2)^{-1/2}(2y)=\frac{3y}{\sqrt{t^2+y^2}}$$

So it seemed to me that from $f(t,y)$ itself we just needed $t^2+y^2 \neq$ because since it involves squares it cannot be less then zero. and from the partial , i thought the same condition would need to hold, i.e. that $t \neq 0 $and $y\neq 0$.

However, the answer given is "Everywhere". So what is happening at $y=0$ and $t=0$?

Maybe I made a very simple mistake or something, or I am not understanding?

Thanks

Comment: Differentiating $y^{3/2}$ you arrive at a power of $1/2$, not $-1/2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your didn't find the derivative correctly. It should be

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{3}{2}(t^2+y^2)^{1/2}(2y)=3y\sqrt{t^2+y^2}$$

Comment: oh yea my mistake, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If only f is continuous: existence; If both f and partial derivative with y are continuous : uniqueness . In this problem existence theorem is satisfied everywhere and also uniqueness is satisfied everywhere hence the solution exists and it is unique in any rectangular domain.